# How I resolve the Cache issues on my reactjs website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, seo

I'm working on reactjs projects the website url is https://websouls.com/ everything is working fine but one of my seo friend visit and report the issue pf chaches. For example he said go to this url cache:https://websouls.com/  and google will have to show the main page of the website but it is showing 404 page.

I checked other reactjs websites cache those are working perfectly fine. Even I asked the server guy who devlop my project on cloudfare.he said everything is good on server side.it maybe issue in the code.

So I'm looking for the help how I resolve this issue.

Thanks

I do some rnd on this but I Couldn't figure it out whats the issue is.

I'm expecting to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are doing client side rendering.You need to use a framework such as Next JS or Remix or Gatsby JS for creating static site versions of your site.Google crawlers have to do extra work to render and index websites which do client side rendering.This is the main issue.Please read up on Next JS

Comment: In this point, changing the framework of the project take time. Everything in on the product. Well thanks you man, I will looking forward some more solutions. So I can stick on reactjs and fixed this issues. If won't then I will go for the nextjs

Comment: Next Js is very similar to React JS. I mean if you already know Create React App or Vite then you can easily learn Next JS. There will be a few new concepts but it is not hard